# Xcode Xib - Black border right and bottom of iOS Simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I'm working with Xcode 8.2.1 and I'm getting these back borders on the right and bottom sides of the device whenever I set the view as a smaller device in the XIB file. There is also the problem where whenever I select iPhone 7 Plus and then run on a iPhone 7 that part of the interface is pushed off the right and bottom of the screen. Everything is currently coded in Objective-C.

[image: Device with black borders]

Update:

Main screen.

[image: View Stack]
[image: View Windows]

Code:

**RootViewController**

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(CurrentLevel == 0) {
        NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        self.tableDataSource = tempArray;
        [tempArray release];

        AppDelegate *AppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        self.tableDataSource = (AppDelegate.data)[@"Rows"];

        self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
    }
    else
        self.navigationItem.title = CurrentTitle;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = (self.tableDataSource)[indexPath.row];
    NSArray *Children = dictionary[@"Children"];

    if(Children.count == 0) {
        DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
        dvController.CurrentTitle = dictionary[@"Title"];
        [dvController release];
    }
    else {
        RootViewController *rvController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;
        rvController.CurrentTitle = dictionary[@"Title"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];
        rvController.tableDataSource = Children;
        [rvController release];
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

NSString *Path = [NSBundle mainBundle].bundlePath;
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Master.plist"];

NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
self.data = tempDict;
[tempDict release];

[window setRootViewController:navigationController];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

**DetailViewController**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@implementation DetailViewController
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
}
```

Comment: that happen when your view is smaller than the screen of the device. You should enable auto layout and add the constraints to make fit to any device.

Comment: @Calc91 I have auto layout enabled and constraints are set everywhere I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having "constraints set everywhere you can" is probably not what you want. It looks like you have set an explicit width and height. Remove all your current constraints and instead set a top, bottom, leading, and trailing constraint with a value of 0 and uncheck 'constrain to margins' (if you want the tableview to fill the view).

[image: Add Constraints]

**EDIT:**

After some discussion in chat, I've realize that this has nothing to do with AutoLayout constraints. Rather, since you are using a XIB for your main window, it is being sized explicitly to the size set in the XIB. All you need to do to have it be sized correctly is tell it what the size of your screen is. Anywhere in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, just add `[window setFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];` and it will resize to the size of the device's screen.

Comment: All the set constraints are greyed out for these views. When I said I set constraints for everything above, that was for a different view which doesn't seem to pertain to this 1 as it is later in the stack.

Comment: Ok, i see in your update that your view is not inside a view controller, so yeah adding constraints like i said wouldn't work. How are you displaying the view in question (the one that's not scaling properly)? I don't see a segue or relationship in your storyboard screenshot. Are you instantiating & preseting it manually? What's the code look like?

Comment: I'm not using segues or relationships as I'm using xib instead of storyboard. From what I understand I believe I'm instantiating the views.

Comment: What is the parent class of RootViewController and how is the UITableView getting placed in it?

Comment: From my understanding, it is the parent class but maybe not. I've added the `#import` headers so as to make the code clearer. Those are the only 2 controllers and the AppDelegate

Comment: I mean, what is RootViewController a subclass of? There is no `RootViewController` in UIKit. It HAS to have a parent class: UIViewController, UINavigationController, UITableViewController. Look in your RootViewController.h file. You'll see `@interface RootViewController : SomeParentClass`. What is the parent class?

Comment: Ah true, I wasn't thinking. RootViewController = UITableViewController, DetailViewController = UIViewController

Comment: Ok. Based on that, I think you need to look at the constraints on your UINavigationController (the one you set as the window's root view controller in applicationDidFinishLaunching:). How does that navigation controller get instantiated?

Comment: There are no constraints set on the UINavigationController as all the options are greyed out. The navigation controller is instantiated at launch as the launch screen and then turns to the main interface.

Comment: It sounds like you have something set up incorrectly in your project and / or view hierarchy. Let's continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136989/discussion-between-jordan-bondo-and-number1).